# How do I perform Non linear Least Squares on a model with predefined lag structure?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, least-squares, gaussian, nonlinear-analysis

Suppose I have the following formula:

$$y_t = \beta_0\sum_{i=0}^p w(\delta;i)x_{t-i}$$

Where $\displaystyle w(\delta;i)=\frac{\exp(\delta_1 i+ \delta_2 i^2)}{\sum_{i=0}^p \exp(\delta_1 i+ \delta_2 i^2)}$.

Suppose now $p = 3$, the model will look like this:

$$y_t = \beta_0\Big(1 * x_t + \frac{\exp(\delta_1 1+ \delta_2 1^2)}{\exp(\delta_1 1+ \delta_2 1^2)+1}x_{t-1}+ \frac{\exp(\delta_1 2+ \delta_2 2^2)}{\exp(\delta_1 2+\delta_2 2^2)+\exp(\delta_1 1+ \delta_2 1^2)+1} x_{t-2}\Big)$$

How do I use Non-Linear Least Squares to find the estimates of the parameters $\beta_0$,$\delta_1$ and $\delta_2?$

I have read something about the Gaussian-Newton Method to estimate these parameters. This iteration method is used to minimize the sum of squared residuals:

$$\operatorname{argmin}\sum_{t=1}^T \left(y_t-\left(\beta_0\sum_{i=1}^p w\left(\delta;i\right)x_{t-i}\right)\right)^2$$

Besides, on this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares they suggest constructing a Jacobian matrix $J_{ij}$ such that the problem becomes linear and the estimator becomes:$(J^TJ)\Delta\beta=J^T\Delta y$ consequently $\Delta\beta =(J^TJ)^{-1}J^T\Delta y.$

However I feel like this is not possible for my problem, therefore I should use the Gaussian method. Can anyone please give me extra information on this topic?

Picture for methodology:
[image]

Comment: Here's what I would do: set up your data in Excel, set up this formula, form the square differences, and then use the Solver routine to minimize the sum subject to constraints by changing the cells containing your coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, do you have such a recommendation for the software package R?

Comment: Not an R user, I'm afraid. That's why I would do it in Excel. There's probably a way to do it, but I don't know it.

Comment: You might get a better answer if you posted in Stats.SE.

Comment: I will post it on Stats.SE I did not know of its existence. Thank you guys for the recommendations.

Comment: I think your expression for $w$ is wrong. The sum in the denominator can't be indexed by the same $i$ as the input. If you would use $\sum_j$, the denominator in the three fractions will be the same

Comment: I do not understand why this would impose a problem.

Comment: I have added a picture to clear up the methodology

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but I just need to see that the formula looks right. The formula for the weights is causing you confusion. Try this (I've changed the summation index)
$$w(\delta;i)=\frac{\exp(\delta_1 i+ \delta_2 i^2)}{\sum_{j=0}^p \exp(\delta_1 j+ \delta_2 j^2)}$$
Then, for $p=2$ $$y_t=\beta_0\frac{1}{1+\exp(\delta_1+\delta_2)+\exp(2\delta_1+4\delta_2)}(x_t+\exp(\delta_1+\delta_2)x_{t-1}+\exp(2\delta_1+4\delta_2)x_{t-2})$$